# JBoss in IntelliJ fails

Tags: intellij-idea, jboss, wildfly

I am trying to launch the `WildFly-8.2.0`in `IntelliJ`.

I am able to connect to the server but the page says `404 Not Found`.

Do I need to set any other variables than JAVA_HOME,JAVA_OPTS in JBoss debug configurations?

Please help me out,

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well adding another path variable regarding my deployment product and then doing `ant clean` and `ant` solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The following two lines show problems:

Caused by: org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceNotFoundException: Service service jboss.ejb.default-resource-adapter-name-service not found

16:26:31,563 INFO  [org.jboss.as.pojo] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS017000: Found legacy bean/pojo namespace: urn:jboss:bean-deployer:2.0 - might be missing some xml features (potential exceptions).

There are JBoss Developer posts about this at: https://developer.jboss.org/thread/199664?tstart=0  and https://developer.jboss.org/message/725587

Are you using the standalone-full.xml?

Comment: I have these lines in  <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:ejb3:1.3"> in standalone-full.xml. `<mdb>
                <resource-adapter-ref resource-adapter-name="${ejb.resource-adapter-name:hornetq-ra.rar}"/>
                <bean-instance-pool-ref pool-name="mdb-strict-max-pool"/>
            </mdb>`

Comment: Should i add the suggested <mdb> tag value to the existing tag or should i replace it?